# Is a one-form a derivation on $C^ \infty$?

Tags: manifolds, tensor-products

I know that a vector field is a derivation on $C^ \infty$, meaning that it is R-linear and Leibnizian. Is it the same case for one-forms?

Comment: One-forms don't take functions as inputs.

Answer (score 1):

A one-form acting on a smooth real-valued function is undefined.